# TypeScript error : Rxjs calls setTimeout differently than defined in @types/node

Tags: node.js, typescript, rxjs

Runtime:

- Node v11.7.0
- RxJS version: 6.3.3
- @types/node: 8.10.45
- tsc: 3.2.4

When running `tsc` I see that somewhere in Rxjs, `setTimeout` gets called without passing the `ms` parameter, and this is against the `@types/node` definition of `setTimeout`. Since I updated to the latest version of Rxjs, I can't build my project anymore.

Is there a workaround ?

```
node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/util/hostReportError.ts:7:3 - error TS2555: Expected at least 2 arguments, but got 1.

7   setTimeout(() => { throw err; });
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:123:65
    123 declare function setTimeout(callback: (...args: any[]) => void, ms: number, ...args: any[]): NodeJS.Timer;
                                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~
    An argument for 'ms' was not provided.
```

Comment: It's not so much a workaround, it's just normal practice to never compile any sources inside `node_modules`. Your project should be using compiled `.js` and `.d.ts` files from its dependencies, not source `.ts` files.

Comment: Wow, this is confusing to me right now because as far as I know I am not compiling anything in the node_modules. I am excluding it from my tsconfig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding the folowing to my `tsconfig.json`:

```
  "lib": [
    "dom",
    "es2017"
  ]
```